# bomb including ordered pairs in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to do this task in python 3:
Get as many Ordered Pairs as the User Wants, Seprated with space, like: (1,3) (5,6) ...
Print a 10 × 10 Square Made with Xs.
except for the Ordered Pairs given, print Os on their place.
Note: the Origin (0,0) of the Imaginary Coordinate System on this Square is the Left-Top place

well I wrote this code:

```
x = input()
L=(x.split())

for i in range(0,len(L)):
    for n in range (0,10):
        for m in range (0,10):
            if (m == int((L[i])[1]) and n == int((L[i])[3])):
                print("O", end=" ")
            else:
                print("X", end=" ")
        print()
```

but it has a Problem: it prints more than one Square. when I give two inputs, it Prints two Squares :(
like this:

```
(0,0) (3,5)
O X X X X X X X X X 
X X X X X X X X X X 
X X X X X X X X X X 
X X X X X X X X X X 
X X X X X X X X X X 
X X X X X X X X X X 
X X X X X X X X X X 
X X X X X X X X X X 
X X X X X X X X X X 
X X X X X X X X X X 
X X X X X X X X X X 
X X X X X X X X X X 
X X X X X X X X X X 
X X X X X X X X X X 
X X X X X X X X X X 
X X X O X X X X X X 
X X X X X X X X X X 
X X X X X X X X X X 
X X X X X X X X X X 
X X X X X X X X X X
```

but it's Supposed to be like:

```
(0,0) (1,2) (3,3) (1,5) (8,9)
O X X X X X X X X X
X X X X X X X X X X
X O X X X X X X X X
X X X O X X X X X X
X X X X X X X X X X
X O X X X X X X X X
X X X X X X X X X X
X X X X X X X X X X
X X X X X X X X X X
X X X X X X X X O X
```

any help would be Appreciated.
I'm a Beginner :(

Comment: Hint: the outermost loop should be, if anything, the innermost loop. The two outer loops should execute a total of 100 times (since you are printing 100 symbols), not a variable number of times which depends on the user's input. If you know about the `in` operator, you really don't need to loop over `L` at all. When you get to location `(n,m)` just check if that tuple is in your list (but you would need to first covert it to a string, or convert the elements of `L` to int tuples).

Comment: The problem is that your outermost loop goes over `range(0,len(L))` - in other words your code says to do _everything_ `len(L)` (the number of inputs) times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import ast
user_input = input()
ordered_pairs = [ast.literal_eval(i) for i in user_input.split(' ')]

l = [['X' for j in range(10)] for i in range(10)]

for x, y in ordered_pairs: l[y][x] = 'O'

print('\n', user_input, sep='')

for i in l:
    print(*i)
```

```
(0,0) (1,2) (3,3) (1,5) (8,9)
O X X X X X X X X X
X X X X X X X X X X
X O X X X X X X X X
X X X O X X X X X X
X X X X X X X X X X
X O X X X X X X X X
X X X X X X X X X X
X X X X X X X X X X
X X X X X X X X X X
X X X X X X X X O X
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```python
x = "(0,0) (1,2) (3,3) (1,5) (8,9)"
x = [eval(i.replace("(", "").replace(")", "")) for i in x.split()]
X = np.array(x)
cols = X[:, 0].max()
rows = X[:, 1].max()

d = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((max(rows, cols)+1, max(rows, cols)+1))).replace(0, "X")
```

d:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X
1   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X
2   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X
3   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X
4   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X
5   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X
6   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X
7   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X
8   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X
9   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X
```

```
R = [i[1] for i in x]
C = [i[0] for i in x]
for i in range(len(R)):
    print("Row:", R[i], end="\t")
    print("Col:", C[i])
for i in range(len(R)):
    d.iloc[R[i], C[i]] = "0"
```

```
Row: 0  Col: 0
Row: 2  Col: 1
Row: 3  Col: 3
Row: 5  Col: 1
Row: 9  Col: 8
```

d:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0   0   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X
1   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X
2   X   0   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X
3   X   X   X   0   X   X   X   X   X   X
4   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X
5   X   0   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X
6   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X
7   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X
8   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X
9   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   X   0   X
```

Comment: This is a bizarre overkill that doesn't produce the intended output (not exactly) and would be mystifying to a beginner.